# How to pass rails model attributes to javascript safely?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, security

I'm trying to pass model attributes to javascript through html like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  myModel = <%= MyModel.all.map{|m| m.attributes}.to_json.html_safe %>;
</script>
```

but, it's not safe, because one of attribute values can be a malicious string:

```
"</script>Evil Code<script>"
```

How to make it safe again?

Comment: Why not pass the attributes from an action in the controller?

Comment: @e3matheus, yes, I'm thinking of it, but I see here two disadvantages: more complicated code and less performance. Since, if I just embed it to html, there is no need to make another request for attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to make a helper function, which escapes each attribute with `h` method:

```
def safe_attributes_of model_class
  attributes = model_class.all.map do |model|
    model.attributes.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v), attrs| 
      attrs[k] = h(v)
    end
  end

  attributes.to_json.html_safe
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first second after reading Your question I assumed that you misunderstood the function of the `html_safe` method, and I said:

> The method `html_safe` has a very misleading name. It does not make your String safe, does not escape the unsafe characters. It just **tells that it IS safe**, what usually is the opposite to what you want.

This note may be useful for some people, so allow me to leave it here. **And accept my apologies** :)

Then I got enlightened that the real problem is that the `<script>` element has "strange" escaping rules, really hard to implement. Basically, the script element content **cannot** contain the string `</script` folowed by `>` or a few white-space characters.

The [HTML5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/scripting-1.html#restrictions-for-contents-of-script-elements) defines a little different rules for the `script` content than [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#notes-specifying-data). Note that in HTML4 *any* closing tag is shown as illegal, while HTML5 considers only `</script>`

The problem is that the character entities are NOT recognized inside script element, so we are left with the task of trying to remove forbidden substrings according to the JavaScript (or any other language) syntax rules. This may be really hard to automate.

If one of these forbidden strings is placed in double-quotes literal, then we may replace it with `<"+"/script`. If it is in single-quoted literal, we should use `<'+'/script`. If it is in a comment.. and so on.

I suppose that in this exact situation we may **assume** (read: "pray and hope") that this *script-end* is always placed in double quotes, and will never be a part of a variable name. This simple `gsub` should work in most cases:

```
<%= MyModel.all.map{|m| m.attributes}.
     to_json.gsub("</script", "<\"+\"/script").html_safe %>;
```

However, I find this excess of faith very disturbing :-(

Comment: then it will escape quotes, needed for valid json strings with `&quot;`, and javascript will be broken

Comment: Yes, You are perfectly right. The rules of escaping `<script>` content weren't so simple as I recalled: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/scripting-1.html#restrictions-for-contents-of-script-elements